# my problem was about rendering html document in django application

Tags: django

"""
this is my view.py file in which i created in order to make view on my html document

```
from urllib import response
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpRequest 
def index(request):
    return response(request,'good/try.html')
```

and also i create the path in urls.py file

```
from django.urls import path
from. import views

urlpatterns = [
       path('',views.index)
   ]
```

My simple html document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>
    
          many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions 
        have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose 
        (injected humour and the like).
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

but when I try to render my html page it raise an error which was:

```
TypeError at /
    'module' object is not callable in the browser
```

Comment: You let your IDE auto-complete the wrong thing for `response`…?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mistakenly importing the `urllib.response` module and trying to call it.

```
return response(request, 'good/try.html')
```

should be

```
return render(request, 'good/try.html')
```